# Sum Jython string

Tags: jython

I need help summing a jython string

The string is not specific

I want the user to type in their name and ascii to sum their name.

word = requestString("What is your first name?")
 for char in word:

As I am not used to jython, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "summing a string" mean? For example, if the user types "John", what exactly is the expected output?

Comment: shows a number for an entered name (either first or last), which is the sum of the positions of each character in the alphabet.
 E.g. If the name is "abby", the number is 30 since a is 1, b is 2 and y is
 25 and 1+2+2+25 is 30.

Comment: What you explained in the comment above should be in the question itself. And there are other things that you should clarify as well. Are only the letters a-z allowed? What should happen if someone enters "José", for example?

Comment: just a-z.. ignore everything else, can you help me or not..